# ES6 and struts 2 dollar sign

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, struts2, template-literals

I would like to ask about using template literals es6 syntax along with struts dollar variable sign

In a jsp i have a script which looks like this :

```
 let formSelector = "form#saveForm div";
 let inputPrefix = `<input type='hidden' name='compositeEx[${index}]'`;

 console.log(`index${index}`);
```

the thing is that when i console.log i get only `index` without the index value.

if i do

```
console.log(`index`+index);
```

it prints the value i want

I am wondering if there is a confict with struts2 ${value} usage and es6 template literals feature there is any documentation for this or a way to use template literals along with struts

Comment: What does the generated page look like ? This will tell you *where* is the problem.

Comment: im actually dont want to print anything i pass these values to struts action like $("form#saveForm div").append("<input type='hidden' name='compositeEx["+index+"].id' value='"+id+"'></input>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i tried to escape the dollar sign and it worked
I guess struts rendering on server renders this:

```
console.log(`index${index}`);
```

to this (index is available after a js function call on jsp script tags context)

```
console.log(`index`);
```

escaping dollar sign :

```
console.log(`index\${index}`);
```

renders to this

```
console.log(`index${index}`);
```

which is usable by javascript

Comment: JSP is rendered before it's sent to the browser. `${index}` will render as JSP EL, because it's valid JSP EL.

Comment: @Dave Newton yes it renders before js and thats why it lefts ${index} empty (evaluated in js script tag inside jsp)

Comment: Yes, I know--I'm both confirming your diagnosis, and reiterating that it's important to understand the actual request flow. There seemed to be some confusion on your part regarding what's actually happening and why.

Comment: yes i think i get it now and why i have to escape dollar sign